# How do I call this jQuery function from an iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to call a jQuery popup window function from within an iframe.

In my external .js which is included in my parent frame I have this:

```
(function($){         
    $.fn.popupWindow = function(instanceSettings){

        return this.each(function(){

        $(this).click(function(){

        $.fn.popupWindow.defaultSettings = {
            centerBrowser:0, // center window over browser window? {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}. overrides top and left
            centerScreen:0, // center window over entire screen? {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}. overrides top and left
            height:500, // sets the height in pixels of the window.
            left:0, // left position when the window appears.
            location:0, // determines whether the address bar is displayed {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}.
            menubar:0, // determines whether the menu bar is displayed {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}.
            resizable:0, // whether the window can be resized {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}. Can also be overloaded using resizable.
            scrollbars:0, // determines whether scrollbars appear on the window {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}.
            status:0, // whether a status line appears at the bottom of the window {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}.
            width:500, // sets the width in pixels of the window.
            windowName:null, // name of window set from the name attribute of the element that invokes the click
            windowURL:null, // url used for the popup
            top:0, // top position when the window appears.
            toolbar:0 // determines whether a toolbar (includes the forward and back buttons) is displayed {1 (YES) or 0 (NO)}.
        };

        settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.popupWindow.defaultSettings, instanceSettings || {});

        var windowFeatures =    'height=' + settings.height +
                                ',width=' + settings.width +
                                ',toolbar=' + settings.toolbar +
                                ',scrollbars=' + settings.scrollbars +
                                ',status=' + settings.status + 
                                ',resizable=' + settings.resizable +
                                ',location=' + settings.location +
                                ',menuBar=' + settings.menubar;

                settings.windowName = this.name || settings.windowName;
                settings.windowURL = this.href || settings.windowURL;
                var centeredY,centeredX;

                if(settings.centerBrowser){

                    if ($.browser.msie) {//hacked together for IE browsers
                        centeredY = (window.screenTop - 120) + ((((document.documentElement.clientHeight + 120)/2) - (settings.height/2)));
                        centeredX = window.screenLeft + ((((document.body.offsetWidth + 20)/2) - (settings.width/2)));
                    }else{
                        centeredY = window.screenY + (((window.outerHeight/2) - (settings.height/2)));
                        centeredX = window.screenX + (((window.outerWidth/2) - (settings.width/2)));
                    }
                    window.open(settings.windowURL, settings.windowName, windowFeatures+',left=' + centeredX +',top=' + centeredY).focus();
                }else if(settings.centerScreen){
                    centeredY = (screen.height - settings.height)/2;
                    centeredX = (screen.width - settings.width)/2;
                    window.open(settings.windowURL, settings.windowName, windowFeatures+',left=' + centeredX +',top=' + centeredY).focus();
                }else{
                    window.open(settings.windowURL, settings.windowName, windowFeatures+',left=' + settings.left +',top=' + settings.top).focus();  
                }
                return false;
            });

        }); 
    };
})(jQuery);
```

In my parent frame I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.popit').popupWindow({ 
        height:350, 
        width:450,
        centerBrowser:1 
    });
});
</script>
```

If I put the following line in my parent frame I get the expected result - popup works:

```
<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk" title="bbc.co.uk" class="popit" name="windowx">BBC<a/>
```

The popupWindow function is associated with the popit class - no problem. But how do I modify the above code in order to call this function from an iframe, and what is the javascript in the iframe to achieve this?

Comment: `call this function from an iframe` you mean, popup the Iframe or create pop up on clicking (or whatever event) the iframe ?

Comment: why can't you have the Javascript and all in the page and just use the Javascript from the page to control the iFrame? Seams more logical and more straight-forward.

Comment: Basically I have an application running in an iframe. Twitter breaks the iframe when you try oauth login from iframe, therefore I'm doing the oauth in a popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code for your iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample code</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($){         
            $.fn.popupWindow = window.parent.$.fn.popupWindow;
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.popit2').popupWindow({ 
                height:550, 
                width:650,
                centerBrowser:1 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="stackoverflow.com" class="popit2" name="windowx">stackoverflow.com<a/>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice how the code is reaching up to the parent to set the function inside of the iframe for local use.

HTH